# Couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.sortable'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and the `jquery-ui-rails` gem (4.0.5). As stated in the [official documentation](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails#require-specific-modules) I can require specific jQuery UI modules. However when I add the `sortable` interaction module I get the following error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Articles#show
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.sortable'
```

My `application.css.scss` file is:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery.ui.sortable
*/
```

How can I solve that problem?

---

**Note**

- The error is not raised if in my `application.css.scss` file I `require jquery.ui.all` instead of `require jquery.ui.sortable` but it is performance less since all jQuery modules are loaded.
- More, it seems that the error with the `sortable` module does not happen for the JavaScript counterpart. That is, I can `require jquery.ui.sortable` in my `application.js` file and all work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery UI CSS Sortable doesn't have any default styling, that's why including it in your application.css.scss file is throwing an error.

https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails (Check under Stylesheet Assets/ Interactions)

Also check rdworth's comment here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortable-css-style-is-not-showing-when-sortable-element-is-not-ul

Comment: I get this with JS also now after upgrade:
`'jquery-ui/sortable' with type 'application/javascript'`, it has moved now to `jquery-ui/widgets/sortable`.